# ajaxtoolkit postback problem

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

i am working on a project.but i have a problem.basically,i am using ajaxtoolkit tabcontainer.assume that i have 2 tabs which i created.let's call them tab1,tab2.in tab1 there is a button and textbox.when i click the button,i am writing some text into the textbox.then i am creating a tab dynamically.assume that it is called "tab3".the problem is when i click the button in the tab1,tab3 is diappearing.how can i prevent this?

```
   <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"  AutoPostBack="true"
        Height="273px" Width="1050px">
        <asp:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="tab1" ID="tab1">       
    <ContentTemplate>
```

tab2

here is where i am adding a new tab in the function:

```
       AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tp = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
        tp.HeaderText = "tab3";
        tp.ContentTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("WebUserControl1.ascx");
        tp.ID = "tab3";
        TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(tp);
```

The html part is: `part:blahblahblahblah`

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with any dynamic controls, you will need to re-add them after every postback.  My recommendation is to store your dynamically-added controls in the ViewState, and write a method that retrieves the information from ViewState and adds your tabs.  Then call this method from Page_Init.

Comment: well i was trying to do that.when i clicked a button i created a new tab.and i added it into viewstate.but in page_load method,i cant retrieve it.here is the code:

Comment: AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tp = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
            tp.HeaderText = "Tab1";
            tp.ContentTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("WebUserControl1.ascx");
            tp.ID = "tab1";
                ViewState["tab1"] =tp;
            TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(tp);
           

            

            //Page.RegisterStartupScript("myScript", javaScript);

            TabContainer1.ActiveTab = TabContainer1.Tabs[4];
            TabContainer1.ActiveTab.Visible = true;

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tp = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
                tp = (AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel)ViewState["tab1"];
                TabContainer1.Tabs.Add(tp);
            }
            
        }